# Php include as html input value

Tags: php, html, text, include

I'm very bad at php but I need this done to continue with the client side code..

Why doesn't this work, a txt file read with php include as a html textarea/input value? The txt file is in the same directory.

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" type="text" class="info-text" size="90" name="cafeInfoBold" class="input" value="<?php include('/cafeBold.txt'); ?>"/></textarea>
```

Comment: Starting the include path with a slash means “look inside `/`”—not in the current directory.

Comment: So it should be `./cafeBold.txt` or just `cafeBold.txt`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That helped when using the placeholder="" but not with value..

Answer (score 0):

just remove the / that before the include function

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" type="text" class="info-text" size="90" name="cafeInfoBold" class="input" value="<?php include('cafeBold.txt'); ?>"/></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks you too, but that doesn't work as value, only as a placeholder.

Comment: as value to the text area or the value=""

Comment: as the value="here" of a <textarea>

Comment: did you add any JavaScript files that overwrite the value of textarea or does the php error reporting turnd off

Comment: What is the php error reporting? And no, I've no js that overwrite the value

Comment: add this to the top of your file "error_reporting(E_ALL);" and if any error displayed please tell me